# How to extract text including spaces in XMLTYPE oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, xquery, xmltype

When I am using the following query,

```
SELECT XMLCast(XMLQuery('/Books/Book' PASSING XMLCOLUMN RETURNING content)
               AS CLOB) "BOOK"  FROM samplexml;
```

Against the xml like below,

```
<books>
       <book>     <title>basics</title> <price>10</price> </book>
</books>
```

I expect the data to be returned as,

`basics 10` , due to the space between title tag and price tag,
but instead I am getting
`basics10`

Edit :
`This is just an example, There may be any number of tags inside them. But I want the spaces to be included even if they are between two tags`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT x.title || ' ' || x.price
  FROM samplexml s,
   XMLTable('/books/book' passing XMLTYPE('<books><book>     <title>basics</title> <price>10</price> </book></books>') 
         COLUMNS title VARCHAR2(150) PATH '/*/./title',
                 price VARCHAR2(1000) path '/*/price') x
```

into XMLTible put the name of the column from samplexml table, e.g. if column is named xdata
transform is such

```
SELECT x.title || ' ' || x.price
  FROM samplexml s,
   XMLTable('/books/book' passing XMLTYPE(s.xdata) 
         COLUMNS title VARCHAR2(150) PATH '/*/./title',
                 price VARCHAR2(1000) path '/*/price') x
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the books, and return strings instead of the books which you can concatenate arbitrarily.

```
SELECT XMLCast(XMLQuery('for $book in /Books/Book return concat($book/title, ' ', $book/price)' PASSING XMLCOLUMN RETURNING content)
               AS CLOB) "BOOK"  FROM samplexml;
```